# Can't find module yarn-3.x.x.cjs (Yarn v3)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install a package using yarn, but I keep getting 'Cannot find module' error. It gives this error when I try to run any command using yarn in this folder. Notably, the error started occuring after I deleted the .yarn folder.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/chronos/user/Downloads/codes/some-react-app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Should I delete my yarn.lock file, or what can I do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

It seems that the link I provided earlier has been removed. It was just the yarn-x.x.x.cjs file that was there. Another solution I found was to delete ALL the global yarn configuration files. On bash terminal that's
`rm -f ~/.yarn*`. Run `yarn set version stable` or your specific version, then run `yarn install` again and you should be good to go

#### Old post:

I found a fix.

For those who face this problem, what I did was, from my project directory, create a directory `.yarn` and inside it another directory, `releases`, then download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GlobexDesignsInc/gxdrecords.com/master/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs and paste in the releases folder.

You should now be able to run yarn commands from your project directory.

Comment: Seems like mentioned link is broken

Comment: dont run rm -f ~/.yarn* . it deletes the global configuration. not recommended. if you must. you can remove just .yarnrc in current project as well as .yarn folder. then in your package.yml , remove packageManager line which points to yarn. from there just run yarn again, set the version if you wish and it will recreate.

Comment: @mirageglobe Deleting global configuration was what I needed, since yarn was misconfigured on my machine. In fact, changing repo configuration is not possible for me at work.

Comment: @PrakharNigam If you need the link, you can check the old commit history. I can't say how long it will be accessible because I don't contribute to or maintain the repository (a simple google search pulled it up). But I managed to pull a new link using this, but I'll just advice you to use the other alternative because it actually solves the problem and prevents further recurrence on the same machine.

The link using the commit history: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GlobexDesignsInc/gxdrecords.com/0f593fc6ed9aa9c8bd88f512f1028a1ed22b0d39/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs

Comment: Dont forget to do this in admin mode, if you do it from normal terminal, the package will not be removed properly and neither there will be any error

Answer (score 12):

Running `rm ~/.yarnrc` and `rm ~/.yarnrc.yml` and worked for me. Don't worry if either file isn't there. `~/.yarnrc` was not found in my case so I ended up deleting `~/.yarnrc.yml` only. I logged out and in to the terminal and ran yarn --version and got 1.22.17

Comment: More specifically, you should edit `yarnPath` property, some users can have important settings at `.yarnrc.yml`.

Answer (score 5):

just to add to above answers. there are two possibilities of encountering this, either you have run yarn (with version 3+) in your global settings `~\` or it might be the project you are working on `~/myfavproject/*` where yarn was previously initated.

a few steps which you can use in your project folder,

- remove node_modules `rm -fr node_modules`
- remove `.yarn` folder which has various *.cjs yarn releases `rm -fr .yarn`
- edit your `package.json` and check/remove the line for `packageManager: xxxxx` see below

```json
  },
"packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1"
}
```

after,

- check your yarn version `yarn --version`
- set your yarn version `yarn set version berry` or `yarn set version stable` if you wish (https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version)
- run yarn again `yarn` which will add the files and also update package.json

Answer (score 3):

I set my yarn version (in yarnrc.yml) to the default yarn (I used homebrew)
`yarnPath: /usr/local/bin/yarn`

Then, I was able to rerun
`yarn set version berry`

Then reset yarnPath to `.yarn/releases/...`

Answer (score 1):

take a look at `yarnrc.yml`,
then change or remove the path