# Yarn project is using yarn3x and Plug 'N Play but doesn't work without node_modules directory

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v3

I'm trying to create a new NestJS project with Yarn as the package manager. After installing NestJS with npm globally (`npm install -g @nestjs/cli`), I ran `npx nest new [package name] --strict`, then selected Yarn as the package manager in the resulting CLI.

A fresh NestJS project is created. I run `yarn` to install the packages, but every module that the files in the generated project try to import throw `Cannot find module`

e.g.:

> Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

It's only when I tried `npm install`, which created a `node_modules` directory, that the imports work. So it appears that the project is using yarn classic/without Plug 'N Play?

However, when I run `yarn -v` in my home directory, I get 3.3.0, so that should mean the global yarn version is 3.3.0 (if there is such thing as a global yarn version)?

`yarn -v` inside this new project also gives 3.3.0, and only in another project that I explicitly set to yarn 1x does the command give 1.22.19.

Furthermore, my project does have the `.pnp.cjs` and `.pnp.loader.mjs` files. So why is it not working without `node_modules`?

I even added a `.yarnrc.yml` file and added this line inside: `nodeLinker: "pnp"` as per [this documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#enabling-it)

Not only that, I also tried both recommendations in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934191/how-to-install-yarn-v1-and-yarn-v2-on-the-same-machine-so-they-can-be-used-inter) about having both yarn 1x and 2x projects but it still doesn't work.

How do I get Yarn 3x plug n play to work???

Comment: @Progman how is this related to hadoop-yarn??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by doing a these mess of steps that I felt I had already done before but somehow eventually worked:

1. `rm -rf ~/.yarn*`
2. `yarn set version stable`
3. `rm ~/package.json`
4. `npx nest new [name]`  *create new project*
5. *pick yarn in CLI*
6. (yarn start:dev already works, but IDE throws error)
7. `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
8. (if you do Shift + Command + P in a TS file, then > Select Typescript Version, you have to choose Use Workspace Version, which should point to the SDK installed in step 8)

(taken from these these threads:

1. [Can't find module yarn-3.x.x.cjs (Yarn v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70976264/cant-find-module-yarn-3-x-x-cjs-yarn-v3)
2. [Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations in NestJs with Yarn 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613878/cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations-in-nestjs-with-yarn-3)

)

Now I'm pretty sure step 2 is actually wrong, because you only do that in a project (i think), which created a project at my home directory, which is why I had to do `rm ~/package.json`. I did this after `nest new` told me that `yarn install --silent` failed, and suggested I remove `package.json` at my home directory. Maybe you're supposed to do `corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate` (from [this doc](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#updating-the-global-yarn-version))?

But it works now, so imma leave it that way ¯\*(ツ)*/¯